# ubuntu 18.04 does not recognize my wifi on HP stream 11

Tags: wireless, touchpad, hp

I recently decided to change my OS on my HP Stream 11 from windows 10 to Ubuntu. Upon installation, it was obvious that Ubuntu works faster, so I figured it was a good idea to keep it. Problem however, it does not  recognize my wifi. Also, the right click on the touch pad does not work. How can I fix that?

```
 lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list   
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:804a]
Kernel driver in use: wl
Kernel modules: bcma, wl
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Ok, great, I think I found the solution for the wifi issue. I am new to all this so plz bear with me.

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04 there is an app called (software updater). If you run this app it opens a window that immediately starts searching the web for updates and gives you only one option; to stop the search. At this point it's your choice to continue the search or stop it. If you do continue, it will find the necessary updates then opens another window with details of that search and a "settings" button. That settings button is where you want to get. (Note: If you choose to stop the search process, you'll end up with a settings option as well)

Comment: When you open settings, you will find a window with six tabs including an "Additional Drivers" tab. If you click on that, it will lead you to a window where it will search for drivers. When the search is done, it will have your wifi driver (Broadcom in my case) recognized but not selected. All you have to do then is select it, click the "Apply Changes" button in the bottom and restart your computer. When it starts again your WiFi will hopefully be working. Very simply but tricky to find through the Software Updater app, because the initial search process is a bit distracting.

Answer (score 0):

I also switched an HP Stream 11 from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 18.04 (and later upgraded it to 18.10),
While the wifi part I didn't have a problem (and I believe you found some help in the comments), the issue with the touchpad right click got me frustrated as well.
The thing is that in Ubuntu 18.04 the defaults for the touchpad is to use finger clicks to define the mouse click, i.e. **one finger click** is a regular **left click** and a **two finger click** is a **right click** (and a **three finger click** is a **middle button click**), once I got used to it I left it by the default as I find it much easier to use than to be limited by the bottom part of my touchpad.
Try installing the `gnome-tweaks` and configuring your desired behavior.
[image: gnome tweaks mouse settings]